# How can I get view pager data in my activity android java

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

**How can I get view pager data in my activity android java**

i create image slider using viewpager i want to get current  viewpager details in my activity

this is my activity  i access view pager and set data

```
 ViewPager2 locationViewPager = findViewById(R.id.locationViewPager);
ImageView next = findViewById(R.id.next);
ImageView back = findViewById(R.id.back);
 genres = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 source = findViewById(R.id.textView2);


List<TravelLocation> travelLocations = new ArrayList<>();


for (int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
    TravelLocation travelLocationMV = new TravelLocation();
    travelLocationMV.imageUrl = R.drawable.cardimage;
    travelLocationMV.genres = "Thriller";
    travelLocationMV.source = "Netflix";
    travelLocations.add(travelLocationMV);
}

TravelLocationAdapter travelLocationAdapter = new TravelLocationAdapter(travelLocations);


locationViewPager.setAdapter(travelLocationAdapter);

locationViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
locationViewPager.setClipChildren(false);
locationViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
locationViewPager.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);



CompositePageTransformer compositePageTransformer = new CompositePageTransformer();
compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(40));
compositePageTransformer.addTransformer((page, position) -> {
    float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
    page.setScaleY(0.90f + r * 0.04f);
});

locationViewPager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
```

this is my  adapter

```
class TravelLocationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TravelLocationAdapter.TravelLocationViewHolder> {

private List<TravelLocation> travelLocations;


public TravelLocationAdapter(List<TravelLocation> travelLocations) {
    this.travelLocations = travelLocations;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TravelLocationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new TravelLocationViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.cardlayout,
                    parent, false
            )
    );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TravelLocationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setLocationData(travelLocations.get(position));
    holder.kbvLocation.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return travelLocations.size();
}

static class TravelLocationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView kbvLocation;

    TravelLocationViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        kbvLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.kbvLocation);
    }

    void setLocationData(TravelLocation travelLocation) {
        Picasso.get().load(travelLocation.imageUrl).into(kbvLocation);
    }
}
```

this is my data class

```
class TravelLocation {
public String  imageUrl;
public String genres,source; }
```

i want to access other 2 field in my activity

i wan to set this filed in activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use interface to access recyclerView data.check this answer how to create interface :
[How to create a interface in main activity and pass the data from adapter to main activity through the interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886536/how-to-create-a-interface-in-main-activity-and-pass-the-data-from-adapter-to-mai)

Comment: how can get current data without click listener

Comment: otherway you get current visible data in recycler through layoutmanager

Comment: Hey @MuhammadAsad can you help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70593277/11560810)